# Node/express postgresql stored procedure / function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure / function in postgresql from node/express. I am using Angular 5.

Installed packages:

- express: 4.16.2,
- pg: ^7.4.0

Other required packages are also installed

Below is the code of my API - I want to replace all queries with my stored procedure / function call

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router=express.Router();
    const {Pool,Client} = require('pg');

    const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:1@localhost:5432/dbAngular'

    // const client = new Client({
    //   connectionString:connectionString
    // })

      router.get('/employees', (err, res, done) => {
        const client = new Pool({
          connectionString:connectionString
        })

        client.connect((err)=>{
          if(err!=undefined)
          {
          console.log('connection not established message as follow '+err.message+'')    
          }
        });
        client.query('select * from getEmployees();', (err, result) => {
          if (err) {          
              console.log(err.stack)     ;
              client.end();  
          } else {                                    
            client.end();
            console.log(result.rows);
            res.json(result.rows);                                  
          }
        })     
    })

    //SAVE
    router.post('/employees', (req, res,next) => {
      const client = new Pool({
        connectionString:connectionString
      })
      console.log( req.body);
    var employee=req.body;

    const query = {
      text: 'INSERT INTO employes(name) VALUES($1)',
      values: [employee.name]
    }

    client.connect((err)=>{
      if(err!=undefined)
      {
      console.log('connection not established '+err.message+'')    
      } 
    });

    client.query(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERRROOORRRRR');
        client.end();
        console.log(err.stack)
      } else {
        console.log('SAVEEEEE');
        client.end();
      //  console.log(res.rows[0])
      res.json();
      }
    })

    });

    //delete
    router.delete('/employees/:id', (req, res,next) => {
      const client = new Pool({
        connectionString:connectionString
      });
    console.log('id passed is ' + req.param.id);
      client.query('DELETE FROM employes WHERE empid=($1)',[req.param.id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('ERRROOORRRRR');
          client.end();
          console.log(err.stack)
        } else {
          console.log('SAVEEEEE');
          client.end();
        //  console.log(res.rows[0])
        res.json();
        }

      });
    });

  module.exports=router;
```

Comment: So what is the issue create a function in postgres and replace node.js query string with function call .what you want ?

Comment: Same comment: what is your issue? do you want us to write code for you?

Comment: Thanks! .. I have created a function and called it.. Its working fine.. But I have to call it like client.query('select * from getEmployees();' .. Is this the correct way ? I made changes in my question as well.. Below is my SP/function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getEmployees () 
 RETURNS setof employes

AS $$

 SELECT
 EmpID,
 name
 FROM
 employes;
 
  
 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;